# How to draw negative y axis for velocity time graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have this velocity-time graph, but I do not know how to draw the negative $y$-axis with its ticks (-1, -2).

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{>=latex} % for LaTeX arrow head

\colorlet{myblue}{blue!70!black}
\colorlet{mydarkblue}{blue!40!black}
\colorlet{mygreen}{green!60!black}
\colorlet{myred}{red!65!black}
\colorlet{mypurple}{red!50!blue!95!black!75}
\tikzstyle{wave}=[myblue,thick]
\tikzstyle{xline}=[very thick,myblue]
\tikzstyle{vline}=[very thick,mygreen]
\tikzstyle{aline}=[very thick,mypurple]
\tikzstyle{mydashed}=[mydarkblue,dashed]

\def\tick#1#2{\draw[thick] (#1) ++ (#2:0.1) --++ (#2-180:0.2)}
\def\tlabel{$t\,\left[\si{s}\right]$}
\def\vlabel{$v\,\left[\si{m/s}\right]$}
\def\alabel{$a\,\left[\si{m/s^2}\right]$}

\begin{document}
% VELOCITY
    \def\xmax{6} % maximum x axis (time)
    \def\ymax{2.0} % maximum y axis (velocity)
    \def\tmax{180} % maximum time on x axis
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\vmax{3} % maximum velocity on x axis
        \def\xscale{\xmax/\tmax}
        \def\yscale{\ymax/\vmax}
        
        % GRID
        \foreach \t in {0,20,...,\tmax}{
            \draw[black!80,dotted] (\t*\xscale,0) --++ (0,\vmax*\yscale+1);
            \tick{\t*\xscale,0}{90} node[below=-1,scale=0.77] {\t};
        }
        \foreach \v in {0,2,...,\vmax}{
            \draw[black!80,dotted] (0,\v*\yscale) --++ (\tmax*\xscale+0.3,0);
            \tick{0,\v*\yscale}{0} node[left=-1,scale=0.77] {\v};
        }
        
        % AXES
        \draw[->,thick]
        (0,0) -- (\xmax+1,0) node[midway,below=9] {\tlabel};
        \draw[->,thick]
        (0,0) -- (0,\ymax+1) node[midway,rotate=90,above=9] {\vlabel};
        
        % GRAPH
        \draw[vline,line cap=round,xscale=\xscale,yscale=\yscale]
        (0,0) -- (40,2) -- (60,2) -- (160,-2);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: tikz]

Comment: Please extend your code example to a full one that is compilable. Your second `\foreach` draws the *y* grid, do `\foreach \v in {-2,0,...,\vmax}` and the second `\draw` after `%AXES` is drawing your *y* axis. Use `\draw[->, thick] (0,-3) -- (0, \ymax+1) …;` for example. Did you consider using [tag:pgfplots] to draw your diagrams?

Comment: Done! Thanks for the solution. But for the grid (the dot vertical grids) they are only showing from y=0 to the y>0, how to make the vertical grids cover from y=-2 ?

Comment: The first `\foreach` draws the vertical grid, you're going to need a negative *y* value here, too. say `\draw[black!80,dotted] (\t*\xscale,-3) -- (0,\vmax*\yscale+1);` (the same `-3` as in my previous comment and dropping the `++`).

Answer (score 1):

If `pgfplots` is not an option, I would draw the grid with the use of the `grid` command, and its relative `help lines` style. Its use is very simple:

```
\draw [help lines] (<x1>, <y1>) grid (<x2>, <y2>);
```

Moreover, as you have defined `xscale` and `yscale` I would suggest putting these options as parameters of the whole `tikzfigure`, like so:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=\xscale,yscale=\yscale,% etc...
```

so that you can use your `t`- and `v`-coordinates instead of absolute geometric x- and y-coordinates.

Finally, I have rearranged the code a bit so it is clearer in my opinion.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{>=latex} % for LaTeX arrow head
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\colorlet{myblue}{blue!70!black}
\colorlet{mydarkblue}{blue!40!black}
\colorlet{mygreen}{green!60!black}
\colorlet{myred}{red!65!black}
\colorlet{mypurple}{red!50!blue!95!black!75}
\tikzstyle{wave}=[myblue,thick]
\tikzstyle{xline}=[very thick,myblue]
\tikzstyle{vline}=[very thick,mygreen]
\tikzstyle{aline}=[very thick,mypurple]
\tikzstyle{mydashed}=[mydarkblue,dashed]

\def\tick#1#2{\draw[thick] (#1) ++ (#2:0.1) --++ (#2-180:0.2)}
\def\tlabel{$t\,\left[\si{s}\right]$}
\def\vlabel{$v\,\left[\si{m/s}\right]$}
\def\alabel{$a\,\left[\si{m/s^2}\right]$}

\begin{document}
% VELOCITY
\def\xmax{6} % maximum x axis (time)
\def\ymax{2.0} % maximum y axis (velocity)
\def\tmax{180} % maximum time on x axis
\def\vmax{3} % maximum velocity on y axis
\def\tstep{20} % step of ticks in t-axis
\def\vstep{1} % step of ticks in v-axis
\def\xscale{\xmax/\tmax}
\def\yscale{\ymax/\vmax}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=\xscale,yscale=\yscale,
  help lines/.style={black!80,dotted,ystep=1,xstep=20}]
  
  % GRID
  \draw [help lines,on background layer] (-\tstep,-2*\vstep) grid (\tmax,\vmax);

  % TICKS
  \foreach \t in {-\tstep,0,...,\tmax}{
    \tick{\t,0}{90} node[below=-1,scale=0.77] {\t};
  }
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\vtickmax}{\vmax+2*\vstep}
  \foreach \v [evaluate=\v as \vv using int(\v-2*\vstep)] in {0,\vstep,...,\vtickmax}{
    \tick{0,\v-2*\vstep}{0} node[left=-1,scale=0.77] {\vv};
  }

  % AXES
  \draw[->,thick] (-2*\tstep,0) -- (\tmax+\tstep,0) node[right] {\tlabel};
  \draw[->,thick] (0,-3*\vstep) -- (0,\vmax+\vstep) node[above] {\vlabel};

  % CURVE
  \draw[vline,line cap=round] (0,0) -- (40,2) -- (60,2) -- (160,-2);
  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Pier Paolo, I will try your code